# How can I create a nested array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

With the code below:

```
var result = [];
result.push({success : 1});
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    result.push({email : rows[i].email});
};
```

I create an array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "success": 1
  },
  {
    "email": "email1@email.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "email2@email.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "emailN@email.com"
  }
]
```

But I want to create an array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "success": 1
  },
  {
    "email": ["email1@email.com","email2@email.com","emailN@email.com"]
  }
]
```

I'm stuck on the exact syntax for doing this. How can I put an array inside another array?

Comment: as an aside, you aren't creating a "JSONArray". you're creating a JavaScript array that is then being serialized to JSON as it's output to the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result = [
  { success : 1 },
  { email   : rows.map(function(row) {
      return row.email;
    })
  }
];
```

Some explanation: `rows` is an array, and arrays in JS have a method [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which can be used to process each item in the array and return a new array with the processed values.

For each item, a function is called with the value of the item, and whichever value is returned from that function is added to the new array.

In this case, the function returns the `email` property for each of the items, so you end up with an array of e-mail addresses, which is basically what you want.

**EDIT**: my initial suggestion was to make `result` an object instead:

```
var result = {
  success : 1,
  email   : rows.map(function(row) {
    return row.email;
  })
};
```

Whether this is better depends on the requirements for the structure of the data.

Comment: Nice and clean solution, one thing to note is that `result` will be an `Object` , not an `Array` as in his example.

Comment: I think you should have also left your initial solution, also mentioning that using an `Object` for the result instead of an `Array` would make everything much cleaner and easier to work with :)

Comment: @Cristy I won't assume that I know better than the OP on how the data should be structured (just how it should be created)

Comment: @robertklep please edit your solution with the initial solution for a better understanding, thank you

Answer (score 5):

The `email` property in the result contains an `Array`, so create one for it.

```
var result = [];
var emails = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   emails.push(rows[i].email);
};

result.push({success : 1});
result.push({email: emails});
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply create an array in the `result` object with the property `email` and then push the emails into it.  See below.

```
var result = [];
result.push({success : 1});
var emails = []
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    emails.push(rows[i].email);
};
result.push({email: emails})
```

Comment: `result` is an `Array`, you can't have named indexes for arrays in JavaScript. (eg: `result.email` )

Comment: @Cristy you can, it just is generally considered a bad practice because you can't get to it using normal array methods. but i'm sure that's what you meant.

Comment: @Cristy, nice catch.  That was a complete oversight on my end.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var finalResult = [];    
finalResult.push({success : 1});
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    result.push(email : rows[i].email);
};

finalResult.push({"email" : result});
```

i think above code will work.